# Windows script to check directory for file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, windows-scripting

Trying to do a bit of scripting to run on a windows server.  The aim of the code is to check a given directory **F:\TestFolder** for the arrival of 1 or more files that start with **IB30321*** in the name.

If the file(s) have not arrived in the given directory then the script sleeps for 5mins before checking again. Once the correct file(s) have been found it exits the script.

Unfortunatly i'm getting the following error, any ideas what i can do to fix this?

> FINDSTR: Bad command line 
>   Incorrect number of files found, 1 file expected

```
@Echo off  
cd /D "%F:\TestFolder%"  

Set numfiles=0

For /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in (      
'Dir /B "IB30321*" ^| findstr /n ^ '  
) DO Set numfiles=%%a&Set filename=%%B

If %numfiles% equ 1 (      
echo %filename% found  
    exit /B 0  
) else (  
    echo "Incorrect number of files found, 1 file expected"  
    set numfiles=0  
    Timeout /T 300  
)
```

Comment: redirect error output of the dir command to nul `2^>NUL`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit more on my comment.

- dir outputs an error message if no matching file(s) found.
- findstr doesn't care what lines it counts.
- suppressing error output on no find will have the do part not executed as there isn't any output.

---

```
@Echo off  
cd /D "%F:\TestFolder%"  

:Loop
Set numfiles=0
For /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in (      
    'Dir /B "IB30321*" 2^>NUL ^| findstr /n ^ '  
) DO Set numfiles=%%a&Set filename=%%B

If %numfiles% equ 1 (      
    echo %filename% found  
    exit /B 0  
) else (  
    echo "Incorrect number of files found, 1 file expected"  
    Timeout /T 300  
)
Goto :Loop
```